# Método authenticate ha dejado de funcionar

Tags: python, django, git, django-models

Tengo una aplicación en Django que funcionaba perfectamente hasta que he intentado lo que dice esta guía: https://scribles.net/deploying-existing-django-app-to-heroku/

Ahora cuando intento iniciar sesión con un usuario, siempre me devuelve un **NoneType**

La aplicación abre normal, puedo recuperar la contraseña, modificarla... pero no iniciar sesión.

La BD contiene al usuario, por lo que no se ha borrado.

Cuando ejecuto la siguiente sentencia en el shell de django obtengo lo siguiente:

```
user = authenticate(username='email@gmail.com', password='1234')
user.name
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Lo que me hace pensar que authenticate me está devolviendo siempre un NoneType, porque el objeto Usuario sí tiene la propiedad name.

```
class Usuario(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12, help_text="The name must be between 2 and 12 characters")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, unique=True, help_text="The email must be between 5 and 30 characters")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=78)
    change_password_code = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=15)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activated_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=15)
    ip = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=15)
    last_login = models.DateField(default=now)
    wallets = models.ManyToManyField(Wallet)
    coins = models.ManyToManyField(Coin)
    avatar = models.CharField(blank=True,default="bitcoin.png",max_length=15)
    delete_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=9,blank=True)
    two_factors_auth = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    two_factors_auth_code = models.CharField(default="",max_length=12,blank=True)
    fingerprint = models.CharField(max_length=64,blank=True)
    private_wallets = models.ManyToManyField(PrivateWallet, blank=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    API_key = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

He intentado solucionarlo ejecutando el siguiente comando:

```
pipenv uninstall django-heroku
```

y eliminando la cabecera que creé en el fichero **settings.py**

Como dato curioso, cuando intento abrir la base de datos de la aplicación sin estar conectado a internet, (está en local, por lo que no debería necesitar internet... y antes no lo necesitaba) me aparece el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Problema en mi código no debe ser porque no he editado nada desde la última vez que funcionaba, tiene que ser algo relacionado con git bash o con dependencias que se han añadido al seguir el tutorial...

**Edito**

Tampoco puedo acceder al usuario administrador desde la pantalla admin de django.

He probado a eliminar la BD y a volver a crearla y sigue sin funcionar.

¿Alguien sabría cómo puedo solucionar el problema?

Mil gracias.

Comment: Has probado acceder con request? El problema es que la variable user es None . Prueba con request.user.name  o self.request.user.name

Comment: Eso no es el problema, porque desde la shell tampoco me sacaba el usuario y request es para cuando el usuario ya está logueado, y mi problema era que no podía loguearme...

Comment: Puedes compartir tu código por git u otra forma para revisarlo?

Comment: Hasta donde tengo entendido, Heroku trabaja con Postgres, intenta seguir [este](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/go-live-with-django-project-and-heroku/) tutorial para ver si se arregla tus problemas, en lo personal no me he tenido problemas siguiendo paso por paso.

Comment: El problema resultó ser que por algún extraño motivo (aún no lo se) mi backend de autenticación personalizado dejó de funcionar, así que utilicé el de django.

Comment: Lo se, pero es una forma de que las personas sepan que no estoy interesado ya en seguir con esta pregunta, y así no pierden tiempo en intentar resolverla

Comment: Puedes hacer 2 cosas: borrar tu pregunta o dejar tu pregunta sin respuesta, nadie te obliga a responder. No toda pregunta debe tener respuesta, las preguntas ya no son de tu propiedad sino de la comunidad, por lo quizas otro usuario quiera responder. Por ejemplo he respondido muchas veces preguntas de hace años donde el usuario ya no esta activo sin necesidad de preguntarle al usuario y le ha servido a otros usuarios. Pero tu *respuesta* puede causar confusión.